# Printing std::strings produces no output

Tags: c++, string

I was building a small template stack class for a side project and it appeared to be working correctly. However, when I tried it with strings it doesn't appear to work. I have no compilation errors or warnings. I simply get no output. I'm a little rusty in C++ but I wasn't expecting to get blocked by a problem that seems this simple.

[image: Example of some output]

My main function (for testing):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "myStack.h"

int main()
{

    bool repeat = true;
    int option = -1;

    std::cout << "Option (1 - String | 2 - Integer) : ";
    std::cin >> option;
    std::cout << "\n";

    switch (option)
    {

    case 1:
    {
        myStack<std::string> stringStack;
        stringStack.push("!");
        stringStack.push("there");
        stringStack.push("Hello");
        stringStack.show();
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        myStack<int> intStack;
        intStack.push(3);
        intStack.push(2);
        intStack.push(1);
        intStack.show();
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Relevant parts of my stack class:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class myStack
{

  private:
    T *elements;
    size_t capacity;

  public:
    myStack();
    T top();
    size_t size();
    void push(T pushed);
    void pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    void show(std::ostream &out = std::cout);
};

template <typename T>
myStack<T>::myStack()
{
    this->elements = NULL;
    this->capacity = 0;
}


template <typename T>
void myStack<T>::push(T pushed)
{
    this->elements = (T *)realloc(this->elements, (this->capacity + 1) * sizeof(T));
    this->elements[this->capacity] = pushed;
    this->capacity++;
}

template<typename T>
void myStack<T>::show(std::ostream &out)
{
    for (int i = this->capacity - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        out << this->elements[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you seem to be missing warnings when actually compiling the source files. The warnings are present only for the linking.

Comment: You can't store `std::string` that way. It is not trivially copyable.

Comment: GCC actually does [give a relevant warning here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cBRiDW).

Comment: Allocating memory for a `std::string` using `realloc()` (or `malloc()`, or `calloc()`) gives undefined behaviour.    If you must dynamically allocated a `std::string`, or a set of them, use operator `new`.   It works with C++ class types that have constructors, including `std::string`.

Comment: @chris so there appears to be a problem in my Makefile correct?

Comment: Oh alright! I was used to malloc() and realloc() and just expected it to work here too.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You may consider a template specialization for the type `std::string`

Comment: @PedroAlves, Appears so. Adjusting `CXXFLAGS` should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of

```
this->elements = (T *)realloc(this->elements, (this->capacity + 1) * sizeof(T));
this->elements[this->capacity] = pushed;
```

to manage an array of `std::string`s is not right. Use of `realloc` to allocate memory is ok. However, it does not initialize the object properly. The second line is cause for undefined behavior since the object was not initialized properly.

If you are allowed to use `std::vector`, use it.

```
template <typename T>
class myStack
{

  private:
    std::vector<T> elements;

  ...
};
```

Then, use of `capacity` can be replaced by `elements.size()`.

`push` can be simplified to:

```
template <typename T>
void myStack<T>::push(T pushed)
{
    this->elements.push_back(pushed);
}
```

You'll have to update `show()` accordingly too.